# Datastore error: Your request included invalid parameters

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to update an entity in data store using admin UI. I get an error 'Datastore error Your request included invalid parameters.'.  Any ideas how to get over this?

Comment: It would be helpful to share your code/more details.  This question is likely too broad for help otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, Brian. Just to clarify, I am trying to do this via the data store console in console.developer.google.com. I have an entity with records. I am clicking on one of these records to transition to an edit screen where I can change the value of the document values and hit 'Save' to persist the changes. Sort of like Query Browser for MySql. When I hit 'Save' GAE is showing me the above error message. There is no code involved. The question is more about do we know what might be causing the issue, as the error message is too generic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error pop-up. From the logs I can see this message:
"Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."

Answer (score 0):

Wrong property data type.

First entity created with a property "A date and time" and "Indexed".

When you start creating second entity **instead "A date and time" will be "An Integer"**.

Hence, error is raised, because data format is wrong.